# Structured trianglar finite element mesh in MATALB

Tags: finite-element-method, matlab, numerical-methods, meshing

The available triangular mesh in the MATLAB PDE tool box [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pdemesh.html) gives an unstructured triangular mesh.

How can I get a structured triangular mesh from the tool box with a similar [data structure [p,e,t]](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/mesh-data-pet-triples.html). See following picture

[image]

Comment: There's something missing in what you've written. It doesn't make sense as it is currently written. I think you've left out some words.

Comment: Write an algorithm to produce the mesh you want. My colleague did exactly that for the package he was using, just need to be pretty good with maths...